# Workaround for firefox 'background-size: cover' bug

Tags: firefox, css

I've got a [really simple page](http://golfclubdiaries.co.uk) which uses a photo as a full-screen background. I'm using the following to define it:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/Hillside.jpg') ;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The image, obviously, takes a little while to load after changing page so I've implemented a noddy jQuery `$.load()` to update the content without the overhead of a full page reload.

Unfortunately, firefox seems to have an issue when the new content causes the length of the page to change. Firefox correctly realises that the scale of the background image has to change and repaints the page behind the content div appropriately - but *doesn't* repaint the rest of the page - hence it looks like 2 differently scaled images are overlaid.

Resizing the window or causing a repaint fixes it. Unfortunately, I can't take a screenshot as it never shows the problem - presumably it does a repaint behind the scenes.

To demonstrate the problem, visit the site, shrink your browser window so that content forces a scrollbar. Change URL using the menu. Look at the image behind the main content in comparison to the rest of the page (About us and Sample Ads are long pages, contact us/prices are short).

How can I force firefox to do a full repaint? I suppose I'm looking for the equivalent of WinForm's `Me.Invalidate()`. Is there a better way to do the background image?

NB: I've shrunk/degraded the photo to reduce file size but haven't spent a lot of time on it yet - I know it can be much better.

**Edit:**
Environment: FF9.0.1 Win7 Ultimate x64.

Steps to reproduce:

- [Browse here](http://www.golfclubdiaries.co.uk/?Page=SizesAndPricing)
- Resize the window so that the white content area is just above the bottom of the browser window (Also, it's handy to make sure you can see some land in the background to make the effect more obvious)
- Click on the "Sample Ads" link
- Click back and forth between Sizes & Prices/Sample Ads
- As you do so, you'll notice that anything to the right of the menu doesn't scale but the image under the menu/content does.

Comment: I don't see the effect listed. What are steps to reproduce the issue, and what version of FF/OS are you on?

Comment: @Ktash Steps and environment added. Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions I got.

The first is simply on loading new content do the following:

```
document.body.backgroundSize = 'auto';
document.body.backgroundSize = 'cover';
```

Just tells it to recalculate the cover area.

The second is very hacky and literally just tells FF to reapply all the styles.

```js
for(var ss = 0, len = document.styleSheets.length; ss < len; ss++) {
    document.styleSheets[ss].disabled = true;
    document.styleSheets[ss].disabled = false;
}
```

That said, I would also report this as a bug to FF (if you haven't already or if it does not exist in the system).

Comment: Thanks, glad someone else has been able to confirm it's happening. I think I'll use the first option for now. I haven't checked the bug db but I will.

Comment: Hmmm, the first doesn't work - even if I `setTimeout()`, so it can't be wrapped up by some optimisation, nothing happens to the background at all. I'm going to investigate but have unmarked as answer until I've confirmed I can get it working :)

Comment: It worked in console but it may be that it is getting optimized out or it is going to fast for it to think it needs to redraw. Did you wrap both in a `setTimeout` or just the second. If it was both, I'd try wrapping just the second item in a `setTimeout(func,0)` to set it to run at the end of the current stack of executions

Comment: I've tried both - in fact I've even tried `b-s: 10px 10px` with nothing to revert it - it changes about 1 time in 10 - looks like the same bug. I'd guess my new content and your changing `b-s` both trigger the event properly but the rendering engine isn't invalidating a large enough area.

Comment: wrt: disabling styles. If I call both in same function, nothing happens. If I do `disabled=false;` on a timeout, I always see a flicker and if the timeout is <~30ms, the glitch remains. Above that, the flicker is very obvious.

Comment: @Basic I'm not sure there is much you can do then. Also, from the looks of it, if the page is wider than about `1085px` the glitch does not happen. My guess is this has to do with the ratio of the image, but it is something to note.

Comment: Yeah, after further playing, it looks like the bug happens when the constraining dimension of the image changes - eg "stretched to fit width" to "stretched to fit height" or vice-versa. I'll leave it for now and file a bug when I get time to simplify to a test case

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem which probably attributes to your issue. Add this to your stylehseet:

```
html, body {min-height:100%;}
```

You see, `background-size:cover;` is only covering the body's physical dimensions. Let's say your `body` is actually only 400px with its content, but your window has 1000px of height. The browser first applies `background-size:cover;` which it does so for the 400px tall `body`, then it sees there's 600px more of space in the window, and kindly applies the background further; in this case, tiling/repeating it. By giving the html/body a min-height of 100%, as above, your body will always fill the available height.

Comment: I did misunderstand your issue, as I thought it was about the vertical tiling I immediately noticed on my tall screen, even though you're using `background-size: cover;`. I encourage you to use my fix for that, even if it doesn't fix your repaint issue.